# error when deploying Twilio service to Heroku

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, twilio

I wrote a NodeJS using Twilio service. The app works perfectly on local but when deploying the app to Heroku I keep receiving the following error
 ***11200 There was a failure attempting to retrieve the contents of this URL*** 
I use the link of my Heroku app ***https://xxx.herokuapp.com/*** as a webhook and I am not sure if it is correct

Comment: Are you able to make a request to your webhook URL on Heroku (either in a web browser or using something like curl or Postman)? Have you updated your webhook URL in the Twilio console from your testing URL to the Heroku URL? Have you setup your environment variables in Heroku correctly?

Comment: I think my configuration is correct since there is no error in my Heroku log. However, under the webhook config in my Twilio console I use the URL of my Heroku app https://xxx.herokuapp.com/sms but it does not seem to work.

Comment: Ok, cool, how about my other questions? Can you make a request to your webhook URL on Heroku?

Comment: I think that is point when the error comes in. When I send the text message/ make a request, Twilio debug console alert the 11200 error instead of sending back a reply message. The application works fine when I test it locally with ngrok though

Comment: So I am not sure if the Heroku URL is the right webhook URL or what else should I look at for my configuration

Comment: Have you updated the webhook URL for the number in your Twilio console? Are you able to make a request yourself (using curl, a browser, Postman) to your Heroku URL? What is the result of making a request yourself?

Comment: Yes, I have updated the webhook URL for the number in your Twilio console. When I make a request in Postman to Heroku URL, the server return the following error:
 <title>Application Error</title>

Comment: It might be best to update your question with the error from Heroku.

Comment: And this is what returned in Twilio debug console:
Msg Service Unavailable
sourceComponent 14100
ErrorCode 11200
EmailNotification false
httpResponse 503
LogLevel ERROR

Comment: Ok, cool, so you're getting an error in your Heroku app. So something is wrong there. Can you check your application logs. You can normally do so from the command line with `heroku logs`

Comment: Heroku does not report any error on its side. My latest log is  "Express server listening on port 24319". Do you suggest anything else I should look at?

Comment: Can You share your express app’s code? There’s something wrong in there and we need to pin it down!

Comment: Sure! I post the code in the comment below

Comment: Is your database connection definitely working? (I assume your `Deal` model is searching in a database.) If your app is just throwing an error, it might be an issue within your `findDeal` method.

Comment: Yes, the database is working well. The error does not throw from the app (Heroku log) but from Twilio debug console. Because it says "Service Unavailable" so I think there is something wrong with the way I configure the webhook.

Comment: Do you have your webhook URL set to https://yourherokuapp.herokuapp.com/sms ? And is it set to make POST requests?

I still believe something is wrong in your app because when you made a request to your app with Postman you got an error. Twilio had nothing to do with that, do you see my point?

Comment: Yes, my webhook URL is  yourherokuapp.herokuapp.com/sms and set to make POST request. Below is my findDeal method
module.exports.findDeal = function(dealRequest){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        Deal.findOne({name:dealRequest}).sort({time: -1}).then(newDeal => {
            resolve(newDeal)
        }).catch(err => {
            reject(err)
        })
    })

}

Comment: Since the app works fine when I test it locally with ngrok so I think it only goes wrong with any kind of deploy configuration. Do you suggest anything else I should look at in my app?

Comment: Can you perhaps try some logging in your app. Can you log the value of `dealRequest` after you retrieve it from the request body. And then can you log the value of the `result` from `Deal.findDeal`. Let me know if that helps at all or if you get one or no results.

Comment: I try to log both the dealRequest and the http request itself but it does not print out in my Heroku log at all. This is the github link to my most updated code so I think it helps you to get the better sense of what is wrong with my application. https://github.com/lanlanle/black-friday-app. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: So, you've pushed the latest version of the app that I can see in GitHub to Heroku and you're not seeing the logs? Do you still get an error if you make a POST request `/sms` with Postman? Can you share the Heroku URL, you can email it to me at philnash@twilio.com if you want?

Comment: Yes, I have pushed to Heroku the most updated version. Postman returning the error saying that it cannot post to the URL. I am emailing my Heroku URL to you now. Thank you so much for all your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It took a while, but I think we got to the bottom of this.

In your [`Procfile`](https://github.com/lanlanle/black-friday-app/blob/master/Procfile) you currently have:

```
worker: node server.js
```

However, you don't want to run a worker process, you want a web process that will receive incoming connections.

So, change your Procfile to

```
web: node server.js
```

Deploy to Heroku and try again.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Twilio documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/11200),

> An 11200 error is an indicator of a connection failure between Twilio
>   and your service. When Twilio requests a page from your server, we
>   wait a maximum of 15 seconds for a response. A connection failure will
>   occur if no response is returned in that time.

The reason for this could depend on the following (but not limited to)

- The application you deploy on Heroku does some heavy operation. Heorku is not provisioning enough resources for it to be completed with in 15 seconds. - Check whether the endpoint sends a reply under 15 seconds.
- Twilio cannot connect your application at all, may be because of port restrictions? - Check whether the endpoint is working
- For some reason, your application is returning a 4xx or 5xx HTTP response to Twilio - Check what your app returns
- Check the other items listed in [Twilio documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/11200) as well.